# How to remove a border when applying Different to two paths?

Tags: inkscape

I have 2 paths (1st image). When I apply `Path -> Different` to them, the border still stays there. How do I remove the border I have marked on the 2nd image?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Case A: The top of the green rectangle hasn't snapped exactly to the top edge of the red rectangle. The green one is slightly off downwards, path difference  leaves a narrow remainder zone to the top edge. The white area is actually a hole.

Case B: The green
rectangle is clearly over the top edge of the red rectangle. Path difference doesn't leave the unwanted remainder. Do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the smaller shape has an overlap, over the edge of the larger shape.

Like this

[image]

Then do the difference operation. Here's the result

[image]